# Optimising map of map data structure

Tags: c++, optimization, stdmap

I want to store a vector of 2D points for every x, y coordinate, to be used as a lookup table with pre-calculated values for a certain aspect of a raytracer.

For this, I created a datastructure of the following type:

```
std::map<float, std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>>> apertureMap;
```

To give an idea of the complexity of the datastructure, the maps and vector will each hold 32 entries.

I can find lower bound values for x, y coordinates by:

```
// find lowest bound x value
std::map<float, std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>>>::iterator it;
it = apertureMap.lower_bound(someInputValueX);
float value1 = it->first;

// find lowest bound y value
std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>>::iterator it2;
std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>> internal_map = it->second;
it2 = internal_map.lower_bound(someInputValueY);
float value2 = it2->first;

vec2 vertex = {it2->second[randomNumber].x, it2->second[randomNumber].y};
```

This all works as expected, but is surprisingly slow. I need to call these two values only once per ray, which means for the next ray it will destroy and create this all again.

**Any recommendations on how to speed up this process?** I would like to use an unordered map for starters, but I need to find non-exact keys, which I think I can only do using lower/upper bounds? I also am not attached to this particular data structure if there would be a faster way.

Comment: `std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>> internal_map = it->second` copies the map. Take it by reference.

Comment: use `unordered_map` unless you really really need ordering, also consider using the `make_heap` functions in `<algorithm>` on a vector of pairs instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
std::map<float, std::vector<vec2>> internal_map = it->second;
```

it makes a full copy of the inner map. Either change that line to make `internal_map` a reference to `it->second` , or remove that line entirely and change the following line to use `it->second` directly.

Comment: Awesome. Speed-up of 1200%. Thanks a lot.